# Management of REST services

Tags: node.js, web-services, rest, sinatra

I have an REST API with different services and it's growing,built in `sinatra` and some parts of it in `node js`. Eventually it's all going to be in `sinatra`.

How can I manage efficiently my REST webservices, check if they are down and relaunching the API, monitor the usage, etc? I've looked into `foreman`, `monit` and `god`, but I'm not sure which one is the most supported. I also would love to be able to manage both languages from the same software.

Comment: Are you asking for a single machine (e.g. something like upstart, etc) or across an cluster of machines (e.g. something like  Marathon, AirBnB's Nerve,etc).

Comment: @eSniff a single machine for the time being; I believe it won't be necessary to upgrade to a cluser in a long time.

Answer (score 0):

you can

1. write a simple shell script that has a for loop of "curl" to your list of http endpoints and put into the crontab with interval based checking.
2. try collectd with curl or other http related plugins to periodically check the responses. and then you can send the results to graphite/opentsdb for persistence or visualization.